# Compare varchar values postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new in the db world and I'm trying to do my first queries.

I have two tables and I need compare the value of the `columnA`, in the first table, with the value of the `columnB` in the second table.

I would like to know what values in the `columnA` are in the `columnB`. Both columns are `varchar` type.

I've tried this two queries:

```
select *
from tableA
join tableB
    on (tableA.columnA = tableB.columnB);

select *
from tableA 
where columnA in (select columnB
                  from tableB);
```

But both get me back empty table.

I checked the values manually, and there are many equal values.

Maybe the `=` isn't the right operator with the string values?

This is a simple example of what I would do, with the expected result at the end.

```
TableA

columnA    descriptionA   
EF8236PA   xyx   
EF7843DV   dgfd
EF6535MD   dshr
EF3274LK   hghg
EF6940BN   fdtsg
EF3405TJ   dsbfbs

TableB

columnB    
EF3405TJ      
EF6940BN   
EF6535MD
```

Result:

```
EF3405TJ
EF6940BN
EF6535MD
```

Comment: Both queries look fine. Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: The query comparison will be case sensitive, when you say the values are equal, are they equal casing?

Comment: please build it on rextester or smwhere else - cant reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all your suggestions, but no one works.

So I tried run the code on another postgre and the same code that I wrote above works.

I don't understand why, the postgre's versions are the same

Answer (score 0):

Both of your queries are looking fine. you can add few more conditions in the where clause that will make it work.

Example:

```
select *
from tableA
join tableB
    on (upper(trim(tableA.columnA)) = upper(trim(tableB.columnB)));
```

Trim will cut down extra spaces and upper will make the search case insensitive.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know what values in the `columnA` are in the `columnB`.

Strictly speaking, this query is a correct (and fast) query to implement what you ask:

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnA
FROM   tableA a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB WHERE columnB = a.columnA);
```

[The manual about `EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS).

But neither of your queries should return empty sets. There may be whitespace or other invisible characters fooling you. Test with:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE columnA = 'EF6940BN';
SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE columnB = 'EF6940BN';
```